# Optimised way to format an 2D float array to a list of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, fastapi

I'm making a web app using fastapi

I have an endpoint named `/distances`

which is outputting an array of float `distances`, from a string input `word`

And then formatting it to a list of dictionnaries to be readable as a json API

```
@app.get("/distances")
async def distances(request: Request, word):

    # batch processing
    distances = await process_batch(word)

    # formatting step
    formatted_distances = [{'d': f'{d:.5f}'} for d in distances]

    return {"response": {
        "distances": formatted_distances}}
```

I'm using a batch processing function to process multiple words at the same time

```
@serve.batch(max_batch_size=MAX_BATCH_SIZE, 
batch_wait_timeout_s=BATCH_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
async def process_batch(words):
    ...
    return distances_list
```

The problem is the formatting step is taking a lot of time to process, and is making a bottleneck when the traffic is high

Is there a faster way to process my distances array to avoid bottleneck ? Maybe directly in my batch processing function ?

Comment: Have you verified that `formatted_distances = [{'d': f'{d:.5f}'} for d in distances]` is the part that's actually taking up time? Is there any need for this to be a dictionary, instead of just a list of distances? What is the type of each measure in `distances`? Is there actually any need for explicitly converting them? It also seems that `distances` is 1D, not 2D?

Comment: It seems fastapi is needing to output list of dict instead of floats (but maybe i'm wrong), I'm reformatting the values to avoid e-18 like values (actual zeros), and distances is 1D, but when I process words by batch it is outputting list of distances, so 2D

Comment: You can return lists (technically they're called arrays in JSON) from FastAPI. If you cant to get rid of super small values (which is a thing that happens in floating point arithmetic), I would guess that rounding would be faster than formatting: `return {"response": {"distances": [round(d, 5) for d in distances]}}`